# Convert Child Class to Base Class for XML Serialization?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a base class `StandardMeasurement` and a derived class `CustomMeasurement` both of which can be serialized.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Load a `CustomMeasurement` from file to `customMeasInstance`.
2. Create new std. meas. s.t.: `StandardMeasurement stdMeas = (StandardMeasurement)customMeasInstance`.
3. Serialize `stdMeas` (only) as a `StandardMeasurement` type.

I get an error when trying because `stdMeas` is still considered a `CustomMeasurement` by the XML serializer. Is there a way I can do this or do I have to "copy" over all the info manually?

Thanks!

Comment: `I get an error` What is this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class, you should be able to do something like this:

**EDIT -** Removed `object initializer` for compatibility with .NET 2.0

```
var cust = new CustomMeasurement();

cust.SomeProperty = "Foo";
cust.AnotherProperty = "Bar";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StandardMeasurement), new Type[] { cust.GetType() });
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, cust);
```

Comment: Well, I'm using .NET 2.0 so I can't try that :\ but I did try adding the `XmlInclude(typeof(CustomMeasurement))` attribute to my `StandardMeasurement` class. It now serializes but includes the child properties that I don't want. Thoughts?

Comment: The `XmlSerializer` class is available in .NET 2.0 too. The `object initializer` didn't come around until 3.5, but you can just initialize the object and set the properties the traditional way.